# Организация галереи изображений

Tags: android-sdk, android

Добрый день!

Вот возникла задачка, думаю какими контролами ее реализовать. Может кто уже делал такое:

1. С сервера грузиться n картинок
2. Нужно вывести картинку на экране
3. При перелистывании пальцем показывать другую картинку.

Казалось бы все просто, но нет. Вешать любой Gesture обработчик (Toush, Measure и.т.д.) на картинку нельзя, так как на ней уже висит обработчик для увеличения/уменьшения двумя пальцами.

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

используйте библиотеку [PhotoView](https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView), она идеально подходит.

- умеет зумить фотки
- работает с ViewPager`ом без проблем (с помощью него сможете организовать перелистывание фотографий)

Answer (score 0):

Добрый день!

Нашел в интернете еще одну очень хорошую библиотеку, как раз она позволяет реализовать выше поставленную задачу в кратчайший срок. :)

Решил поделиться с общественностью - https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

Библиотека называется **Universal Image Loader for Android** и позволяет не только асинхронно грузить изображения, но и отображать их по разному, в моем случае ввиде галереи (картинка на страницу)

Удачи, всем.